# How to install opencv that was built with CMAKE build option to venv?

Tags: python, opencv, python-venv

How to install `opencv that was built with CMAKE build option` to venv ?

Usually when I want to use opencv in venv, I was usually execute `pip install opencv-python`.
However if so, the opencv is the one built by default option.

Is there are ideas to install `opencv that was built with CMAKE build option` ?

What I tried :

- I googled how to pip install opencv-python by specify CMAKE build option,
  but there are no information about this.
- Check opencv-python reference , but no information.
  https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python

Comment: Sure, the binaries just need to be somewhere Python can find them (i.e. one of the paths set in `sys.path`). Been doing that for years now, in fact I have ~15 different versions of OpenCV installed side-by-side to help hunting down bugs and reproducing various odd issues people ask about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPI Official site tells us how to create manual-built whl of python-opencv .

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

> Manual builds
>
> If some dependency is not enabled in the pre- built wheels, you can also run the build locally to create a custom wheel.